# Convert timestamp format in PHP

Tags: php, datetime, timestamp, strtotime

I received a response from the api which has a data field "created_time":1568717579, then I converted it to Ydm H: i: s format to save to my database in PHP, The problem is that it always returns in 1970.

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1568717579/1000);die;
// always returns year 1970
```

Comment: Don't divide by 1000: `date("Y-m-d H:i:s", 1568717579);` gives me `2019-09-17 10:52:59`

Comment: That timestamp is not in microseconds. There is no need to divide by 1000. By doing so you literally are moving the date back by decades.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm stupid, the format is strtotime, not timestamp

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simple

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', 1568717579);

// Utc current time seconds from 00:00:00 UTC on 1 January 1970
echo time(); 

// Current time date
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

Comment: "Simple" does not make for a good answer. You should explain *how* and *why* this solves their problem. I recommend reading, "[How do I write a good answer?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to divide it by 1000. The timestamp is in Epoch(Unix time) format: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm so stupid, it's strtotime